# terraform use count index in module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to use the count.index in the terraform module for my aws ec2 instance to name the instance in increment order

```
file: ec2/main.tf
 resource "aws_instance" "instance"{
    ami = "ami-xxx"
    tags {
     Name = "var.instance"
     }
    count = "var.count"

}
```

```
file: ec2instance.tf

module "ec2"{
 source = "./ec2"
 count = 3
 instance_name = "firsttypeinstance-${count.index+1}"
}

module "ec20"{
 source = "./ec2"
 count = 2
 instance_name = "secondtype-${count.index+1}"

}
```

I want the instance name to be populated as

firsttypeinstance-1
firsttypeinstance-2
firsttypeinstance-3

secondtype-1
secondtype-2

but i get the error that i cannot use count index in the module

Answer (score 1):

[From terraform doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html):

> In addition to the above, the argument names `count`, `for_each` and `lifecycle` are not currently used by Terraform but are reserved for planned future features.

however, you could create the `my_count` variable in your module and use it on resources inside your module

**module ec2**

```shell
resource "aws_instance" "instance"{
    ami = "ami-xxx"
    tags {
        Name = "var.instance-${count.index}"
    }
    count = "var.my_count"
}
```

**module main**

```shell
module "ec2"{
   source = "./ec2"
   my_count = 3
   instance_name = "firsttypeinstance" ## actually instance prefix
}
```