# How to use different different user_data template for multiple instance with ec2 module

Tags: count, terraform

I am new in terraform my requirement is to launch multiple instances to a common ec2 module with different user_data.

my maif.tf file:

```
    provider "aws" {
    region     = "${var.region}"
    profile    = "${var.aws_profile}" #.aws/credentials
    }
variable "count" {
  default = 3
}
variable "hostnames" {
  default = {
    "0" = "testcase_1.sh"
    "1" = "testcase_2.sh"
    "2" = "testcase_3.sh"
  }
}
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  // here we expand multiple template_files - the same number as we have instances
  count = "${var.count}"
  template = "wrf_testcase.sh"
  vars {
    // that gives us access to use count.index to do the lookup
    hostname = "${lookup(var.hostnames, count.index)}"
  }
}
module "ec2" {
    source = "/././modules/ec2"
    count = 3
    user_data              = "${element(data.template_file.user-data.rendered, count.index)}"
}
```

My ec2 module:

```
 resource "aws_instance" "application" {

  count                         = "${var.count}"
  ami                           = "${var.ami}"
  availability_zone             = "${var.availability_zone}"
  ebs_optimized                 = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  instance_type                 = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name                      = "${var.key_name}"
  monitoring                    = "${var.monitoring}"
  vpc_security_group_ids        = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
  subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet_id}"
  associate_public_ip_address   = "${var.associate_public_ip_address}"
  iam_instance_profile          = "${var.iam_instance_profile}"
  user_data                     = "${var.user_data}"
  tags                          = "${merge(var.tags, map("Name", 
  format("%s", var.instance_name)))}"
}
```

Error: module "ec2": count variables are only valid within resources

Comment: Error: module "ec2": count variables are only valid within resources

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you've tried and why that doesn't work for you. If it's erroring then show your exact error. If it doesn't error but doesn't give you what you want could you clearly explain why it's not doing exactly what you want?

Comment: I have tried this one.

Comment: It's telling you you can't use the keyword `count` with modules. There's a whole bunch of duplicate questions of this including this from the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241761/terraform-use-count-index-in-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variance in attributes based on count.index in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186380/variance-in-attributes-based-on-count-index-in-terraform)

Comment: Yes I know, But this shouldn't happen

Comment: What do you mean it shouldn't happen? It's a reserved keyword and you're trying to use it when you aren't allowed. You can use something like `instance_count` if you want to be able to tell the module how many to create but you need to handle that inside the module instead of a naive interpretation of that being to create 3 modules of 1 instance each.

Comment: I tried with different name instance_count and my requirement is to create 3 instances with different - different  user_data templete.

Answer (score 0):

count.index does not work with module's so better approach use in single .tf file it will work.

```
variable "instance_count" {
  default = 3
}

variable "hostnames" {
  default = ["testcase_1.sh", "testcase_2.sh",
  "testcase_3.sh"]
}

data "template_file" "user-data" {
  count    = "${length(var.hostnames)}"
  template = "${file("${element(var.hostnames, count.index)}")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "application" {
  count                       = "${var.instance_count}"
  ami                         = "${var.ami}"
  availability_zone           = "${var.availability_zone}"
  ebs_optimized               = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  monitoring                  = "${var.monitoring}"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
  subnet_id                   = "${var.subnet_id}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.associate_public_ip_address}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${var.iam_instance_profile}"
  user_data                   = "${element(data.template_file.user-data.*.rendered, count.index)}"
  tags = "${merge(var.tags, map("Name", format("%s", var.instance_name)))}"
}
```